# Aligning child in fixed width LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm unable to center-align a child inside a `LinearLayout` that uses a fixed width. As far as I can see, this should be possible by setting the `gravity` flag on the `LinearLayout` but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is the code:

```
LinearLayout hbox = new LinearLayout(getContext());                                     
hbox.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorMultiple, typedValue, true);         

CheckedTextView ctv = new CheckedTextView(getContext());            
ctv.setCheckMarkDrawable(typedValue.resourceId);

params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
ctv.setLayoutParams(params);

hbox.addView(ctv);

params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
hbox.setLayoutParams(params);
```

As you can see, the `CheckedTextView` uses `WRAP_CONTENT` so it should be possible to align it. Its parent `LinearLayout` uses a fixed width of 200 pixels and `gravity` set to `Gravity.CENTER`. Still, it isn't center-aligned but the checkbox always appears on the left side of the `LinearLayout`, not in the center.

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, setting `params.gravity` was wrong because this corresponds to the alignment of `hbox` within its parent. What I want, though, is to set the alignment of the children of `hbox`, so it has to be like this instead:

```
params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
hbox.setLayoutParams(params);
hbox.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Then it works.